# defining attribute type in UML if using PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, uml

As my PHP projects are getting larger and more complex, I am looking to use UML to help me plan and design better systems. This is the point where I wish I had paid more attention to those boring as hell UML classes in college. Anyway, since PHP is loosely typed, is it still necessary to define the attribute type in the class? Is it just purely to conform to the UML standards or just something that I don't really need to worry about in developing my class diagrams for PHP? Of course this isn't a show stopper for me but something I was more or less pondering about.

Comment: Haven't done UML since university, and didn't really do much of it even then, so my advice may be completely invalid - but certainly as a general note on how to think about systems designed in PHP, regardless of it being loosely typed, you should ALWAYS be aware and conscious of the types of all of your variables, so I would think the answer would be that it is still necessary.

Comment: actually that is what i was leaning towards. because ultimately UML should be language independent. I just wanted to hear what the experts had to say on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class diagram in UML is not completely independent of the language used. You can have multiple inheritance in some programming languages and not in others for instance. Some languages provide function overloading, some languages provide operator overloading. That will have its influence how you will develop your classes.

In the UML diagram you should describe what you have made or will use. Not what you might have used if you would have used it. If you are using loosely typed attributes, then should that return in the design of your classes. Otherwise will people see a discrepancy between what you said you have designed and what is used. That makes it much more difficult to maintain the application. Always have in mind that you make the UML not only for yourself, but for that other programmer who will maintain your application afterwards.

The bigger and more complex your programs become, the more structure you will need imo to make it work. Strong typing is a way to help the designer to understand where happens what. The question could have been:
will strong typing help me better designing and maintaining my bigger and more complex PHP projects? If it does (Yes in my opinion), then is it better for you to use strong typed attributes and hence add those strongly typed attributes to your classes.
If you are convinced that strong typing is not helpful at all, then don't use it in your classes and don't describe in your UML.

Comment: I'm more or less agreeing with you on the answer because I liked what you said regarding maintainability. My group is having some issues regarding this now and whatever it takes to make code easier to read and more maintainable is good in my book. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You're welcome. I am interested in the less agreeing as well. :-) Besides UML do I use mock testing to support maintainability. When the application exists for a long time then I prefer to test if the data model still matches the business model. Success!